# I am looking for two single words, both similar!

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

When someone throws something or someone out of a window, we have a word for it: **Defenestrate**

The meaning of defenestrate given by Oxford [Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/defenestration):

> *formal* or ,*humorous* The action of throwing someone out of a window:
>
> *'death by defenestration has a venerable history'*

I am looking for two words similar to it:

1) - To throw someone/something **out of a moving car.**
2) - To throw someone/something **from a rooftop.**

I could not find any.

Comment: You'll have to make them up.

Comment: @snailboat Like?

Comment: Like - *detrabbed*, a verb?

Comment: How about *topple* for the second?

Comment: @MamtaD Topple is good, but it isn't what I am looking for. It's related to crimes. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Funnily enough, there's actually a similar question on ELU (though the suggestions in the answers are similarly made up, and don't really fit the definition *they're* looking for, let alone yours) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230324/is-there-a-parallel-to-defenestration-for-buses

Comment: Isn't the goal of using language communication? What's the good in using words a small fraction of people have heard of? Get your message across; it doesn't have to be a single word, phrase, or sentence.

Comment: The reason you may not find any words/phrase because throwing out of 'window' was a ritual or a popular process of execution *and* the latter two examples aren't! So, there may not be special expression for that.

Comment: @MaulikV [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283511/i-am-looking-for-two-single-words-both-similar?noredirect=1#comment630387_283511) You can understand why I need it. But I will go with the usual phrase. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We simply don't have in English the words you're looking for. Further, "defenestrate", while known by some, is really only used in connection with the start of WWI. You'll just have to spell your variations out.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "really only used in connection with the start of WWI". I know defenestrate from various more modern media (like t-shirts that refer to auto-defenestration) where it was intended to be somewhat humorous. Google NGrams shows it peaked in writing around 2000. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=defenestrate&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdefenestrate%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Specifically, @ColleenV, The Defenestration of Prague. The high school history class that covered that was the first time I ever heard the word, and I've heard it only rarely since then, usually in direct or backhanded references to the same.